Recyclerlistview in nextJS
I am showing infinite list of products in homepage
I spent few days working on building the list using .map loop
{products.map((product) => (<RenderProduct product={product} />))}
However, i am not satisfied with the performance, i have another version where i been using Expo with Nextjs and FlashList.
There is huge difference in performance
I tried to install flashlist and flatlist in our nextjs project but so many errors showed up and i think it is a big shift
My questions:
1- Is flashlist really does not work with nextjs or i am not actually installing it properly?
2- is there something similar to flashlist available to nextjs?
3- Is actually .map loop that slow or i am not implmenting it properly?
